# Understanding why updates to a parent do not update in child sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm just getting to grips with relationships in SQL. Can someone please explain in the following code why, when I change the parent's name from Peter to Charles, this does not update the Child's (Elizabeth's) parent_name - this remains Peter even though I have updated it to Charles?

Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Parent(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    children = db.relationship("Child", backref="parent")

class Child(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_name = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parent.name'))
```

Here is the console:

```
>>> from database_test import Parent, Child
>>> Peter = Parent(name='Peter')
>>> db.session.add(Peter)
>>> db.session.commit()
>>> Elizabeth = Child(parent=Peter)
>>> Peter.children
[<Child 2>]
>>> db.session.add(Elizabeth)
>>> db.session.commit()
>>> Charles = Parent.query.filter_by(name='Peter').first()
>>> Charles.name = 'Charles'
>>> Elizabeth.parent_name
'Peter'
>>> db.session.commit()
>>> Elizabeth.parent_name
'Peter'
>>> Sam.name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Sam' is not defined
>>> Peter.name
'Charles'
```

Comment: The foreign key in `Child` should be `parent_id`, not `parent_name`, because `Parent.id` is the primary key. Also the convention is to avoid *instance* names that start with an uppercase letter – use `peter = Parent(name='Peter')`.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the foreign key in `Child` should be `parent_id`, not `parent_name` because `Parent.id` is the primary key. If you want the `Parent.name` to be directly accessible from the `Child` object you can add a relationship there, too, e.g.

```py
class Parent(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    children = db.relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")


class Child(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = db.relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")


parent1 = Parent(name="Peter")
child1 = Child(name="Elizabeth", parent=parent1)
print(child1.name)  # Elizabeth
print(child1.parent.name)  # "Peter"
```

Then if you change the name for `parent1` the change will be reflected in `child1`:

```py
parent1.name = "Charles"
print(child1.parent.name)  # "Charles"
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Gord, this has solved it for me!